# Conditions for violation of Jacobi identity for covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, connections

I wish to know if there is a situation when the Jacobi identity for the covariant derivative $\nabla_{\mu}$ $$\chi_{\mu\nu\rho}\equiv [\nabla_{\mu}, [\nabla_{\nu}, \nabla_{\rho}]]+[\nabla_{\rho}, [\nabla_{\mu}, \nabla_{\nu}]]+[\nabla_{\nu}, [\nabla_{\rho}, \nabla_{\mu}]] = 0$$ can be violated. Can anyone suggest an example where this may happen?

Edit: Just for the sake of adding some context. Consider a connection with torsion. Then, one will find that

$$[\nabla_{\mu}, \nabla_{\nu}]\varphi = 2T^{\lambda}_{~~~\mu\nu}\partial_{\lambda}\varphi$$ where $T^{\lambda}_{~~\mu\nu} = \Gamma^{\lambda}_{[\mu\nu]}$. Now, we may look at $$[\nabla_{\rho},[\nabla_{\mu}, \nabla_{\nu}]] = 2\nabla_{\rho}T^{\lambda}_{~~\mu\nu}\nabla_{\lambda}+2T^{\lambda}_{~~\mu\nu}T^{\tau}_{~~\rho\lambda}\nabla_{\tau}$$
which implies that
$$\chi_{\mu\nu\rho} = 2\nabla_{\rho}T^{\lambda}_{~~\mu\nu}\nabla_{\lambda}+2T^{\lambda}_{~~\mu\nu}T^{\tau}_{~~\rho\lambda}\nabla_{\tau} + \text{cyclic}(\mu, \nu, \rho) $$
which will only be satisfied if torsion is zero. It seems the Jacobi identity is violated unless one works with a specific kind of torsion. Am I correct in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first of all, the Jacobi identity is always true for the covariant derivative. If $\psi$ is a section of any vector bundle on which the covariant derivative acts (indices suppressed), we have $$ [\nabla_i,[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]]\psi=\nabla_i[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]\psi-[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]\nabla_i\psi \\ = \nabla_i\nabla_j\nabla_k\psi-\nabla_i\nabla_k\nabla_j\psi-\nabla_j\nabla_k\nabla_i\psi+\nabla_k\nabla_j\nabla_i\psi. $$
If we take the cyclic sum, we get
$$[\nabla_i,[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]]\psi+\text{cyclic}
=\color{red}{\nabla_i\nabla_j\nabla_k\psi}+\color{green}{\nabla_j\nabla_k\nabla_i\psi}+\color{purple}{\nabla_k\nabla_i\nabla_j\psi}
\\ -\color{blue}{\nabla_i\nabla_k\nabla_j\psi}-\color{brown}{\nabla_j\nabla_i\nabla_k\psi}-\nabla_k\nabla_j\nabla_i\psi
\\ -\color{green}{\nabla_j\nabla_k\nabla_i\psi}-\color{purple}{\nabla_k\nabla_i\nabla_j\psi}-\color{red}{\nabla_i\nabla_j\nabla_k\psi}
\\ +\nabla_k\nabla_j\nabla_i\psi+\color{blue}{\nabla_i\nabla_k\nabla_j\psi}+\color{brown}{\nabla_j\nabla_i\nabla_k\psi}. $$ The identically colored pairs cancel pairwise, hence the Jacobi identity is true for the covariant derivative.

---

What (apparantly) stumps OP is that if the covariant derivatives are expanded explicitly, we get - combined with the Jacobi identity - a nontrivial identity. Which is btw faulty in the OP.

For a scalar field $\phi$, the Ricci identity is $$ [\nabla_i,\nabla_j]\phi=-T^k_{\ ij}\nabla_k\phi, $$ whereas for a covector field $\omega_i$, the Ricci identity is $$ [\nabla_i,\nabla_j]\omega_k=-R^l_{\ kij}\omega_l-T^l_{\ ij}\nabla_l\omega_k. $$

We thus get $$ [\nabla_i,[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]]\phi=\nabla_i([\nabla_j,\nabla_k]\phi)-[\nabla_j,\nabla_k]\nabla_i\phi=\nabla_i(-T^l_{\ jk}\nabla_l\phi)+R^l_{\ ijk}\nabla_l\phi+T^l_{\ jk}\nabla_l\nabla_i\phi \\ =(R^l_{\ ijk}-\nabla_i T^l_{\ jk}+T^p_{\ jk}T_{\ ip}^l)\nabla_l\phi, $$ hence we get the relation (the cyclic permutation is up to a constant factor same as the antisymmetrization) $$ R^l_{\ [ijk]}=\nabla_{[i}T^l_{\ jk]}-T^l_{\ [i|p|}T^p_{\ jk]}. $$

This is nothing else than the "algebraic" Bianchi identity (which is only truly algebraic if the torsion vanishes), which has been obtained as a *consequence* of the Jacobi identity.

Answer (score 1):

1. For what it's worth, the [Jacobi identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_identity) (JI) follows immediately from the [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property) of composition of [operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(mathematics)), so any violation of the JI must somehow violate this premise. E.g. the [unbounded operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbounded_operator) could be defined on a domain where composition is not well-defined. (Another idea is to act on a non-associative [Colombeau algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombeau_algebra), although I have not tried to work out any examples.)
2. In case of torsion, let us mention that the [second Bianchi identity](https://www.mathphysicsbook.com/mathematics/riemannian-manifolds/manifolds-with-connection/second-bianchi-identity/) (whose proof uses the JI repeatedly) acquires extra torsion terms.

Comment: I believe if the connection has torsion, the Jacobi identity cannot be satisfied unless you put some constraints on the torsion. But I have not seen this statement made anywhere, so I am just looking for a confirmation.

Comment: So you agree that torsion can violate Jacobi identity?

Comment: @Dr.user44690 No, it does not. If you write out the Jacobi identity explicitly, you will see that all terms pairwise cancel. This relies only on the fact that repeated covariant differentiation is - by definition - associative, i.e. $\nabla_i\nabla_j\nabla_k=(\nabla_i\nabla_j)\nabla_k=\nabla_i(\nabla_j\nabla_k)$. You do not need to expand the covariant derivatives in terms of partials and connection coefficients and torsion does not appear whatsoever.

Comment: @BenceRacskó That is incorrect. I just wrote how the Jacobi identity looks like in presence of torsion in the question. It doesn't cancel out.